# Inserting a row at the specific place in SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite, insert-update

I was creating the database in SQLite Manager & by mistake I forgot to mention a row.

Now, I want to add a row in the middle manually & below it the rest of the Auto-increment keys should be increased by automatically by 1 . I hope my problem is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't care about key values, just append your row at the end. Why do you think it is important in your case?

Comment: so cut the rows after position x to a temp table, then insert your record that will placed at position x, then copy the copied data from temp to the table. OR update (`row_no=row_no+1`) the data after x position and insert a row with value x, and don't forge to create a clustered index for row_no field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't care about key values, just append your row at the end.

If you really need to do so, you could probably just update the keys with something like this. If you want to insert the new row at key 87

Make room for the key

```
update mytable
set key = key + 1
where key >= 87
```

Insert your row

```
insert into mytable ...
```

And finally update the key for the new row

```
update mytable
set key = 87
where key = NEW_ROW_KEY
```

Comment: Does this (still) work ? I get **UNIQUE constraint failed** errors. I suspect it depends on the order in which the row are updated, which is arbitrary (according to SQLite docs)

Comment: @bwt With a unique constraint on `key`, this sounds plausible. So in this case, you could either drop the constraint temporarily (if this is possible, I don't know), or move the rows to a temporary table and copy back afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

I would just update IDs, incrementing them, then insert record setting ID manually:

```
CREATE TABLE cats (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR
);
INSERT INTO cats (name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO cats (name) VALUES ('Mark');
SELECT * FROM cats;

| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mark |

UPDATE cats SET ID = ID + 1 WHERE ID >= 2; -- "2" is the ID of forgotten record.
SELECT * FROM cats;

| 1 | John |
| 3 | Mark |

INSERT INTO cats (id, name) VALUES (2, 'SlowCat'); -- "2" is the ID of forgotten record.
SELECT * FROM cats;

| 1 | John    |
| 2 | SlowCat |
| 3 | Mark    |
```

Next record, inserted using AUTOINCREMENT functionality, will have next-to-last ID (4 in our case).