# Inserting a row at the specific place in SQLite database 2022

Tags: sqlite

I have a small database (4 rows) in SQLite and I would like to insert a new row at the place 2.
My table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhNVm.jpg)

I did use this command to re-numbering my primary key id:

```
UPDATE OR IGNORE Films SET id = id + 1 WHERE id > 1;
```

but as the result I am getting this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoNKi.jpg)

It means that there is only row 5 with correct number.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the purpose of primary keys.  They don't specify an order of records; you don't have to rearrange the numbers every time you add a record.  If you want a specific sort order, add a new field and put your sorting numbers there.

Answer (score 1):

The update fails (and is ignored) for every line (except for the one with the biggest id) because there is already a line with the same value.

You cannot control the order of the update.

You could use some trick like :

```
UPDATE Films SET id = id + 1000001 WHERE id > 1;
UPDATE Films SET id = id - 1000000 WHERE id > 1;
```

but a much better solution would be to add a separate column, for example named Order, so that renumbering would not be a problem :

```
UPDATE Films SET Order = Order + 1 WHERE Order > 1;
```

Comment: It is nice. So, this advice is a fake ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629022/inserting-a-row-at-the-specific-place-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

Thw BWT answer is very suspicious because there is this reply:

[Inserting a row at the specific place in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629022/inserting-a-row-at-the-specific-place-in-sqlite-database)

claiming that it is possible.

Comment: Very strange, I tried and it just doesn't work. Anyway updating the primary key is usually not a god idea